# Girl in a marshy village setting whose friend is small with big feet

Tags: identification-request

I remember three things about a book I read as a child.

1. The cover was blue-green, and had either stars, fireflies, or some other kind of orbs of light on it. I don't remember the title, and all of these memories are fuzzy.
2. There was a small character, maybe the main character's best friend. I remember he had large feet.
3. I believe the setting was a past summer in a swampy, humid environment.
4. I believe the target age range was 12-15
5. The plot may have involved a murder or had a theme of growing up.
6. The book was in English and probably set in America.
7. The book was not Bogwoppit, The True Blue Scouts of Sugar Man Swamp nor was it related to the Chronicles of Narnia.
8. The book may have been published around the 1990s

Does anyone know the title of this book?

Comment: I can try to remember more, but you'd have to ask me questions.

Comment: There's a [checklist of questions in the story-ID tag description](https://literature.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info), listing some basic details which might help to jog your memory. Specifically for this question, do you remember anything about the *plot* or what happens in the story? All we have here are cover, characters, and setting. Also helpful info would be when did you read it and what was the target age range. Was it a picture book, or how much text was there?

Comment: I don't remember the plot at all. Sorry. Maybe a murder involved? Or something about growing up? I don't remember exactly when I read it, but I believe the target age range was 12-15. Is that helpful?

Comment: The book seemed somewhat older, but it was in good condition. Hard to tell.